# GitHub wiki directories

Tags: github, wiki

Does the wiki that installs with a GitHub repo support directories?  Our wiki is cluttered with pages, and we are looking for a way to organize them better.

We tried pulling the repo, creating local directories, and moving things around, but when committed back, the wiki didn't pick up the changes.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I was having the exact same issue and tried variants of what you tried.  Nothing stuck.  Asked GitHub support about it and received a reply that essentially said "No, but we'll let the developers know that people are interested in this feature."

So the short answer is "No", and the long answer is "No, but maybe in the future."

Comment: The current short answer is "Yes". :)

Comment: @Marco After THREE years? GitHub really takes their user's request seriously! :|

Comment: Yep, still no, five years later

Comment: Six years. Btw, heard people moaning about #Microsoft got the #GitHub back in the office. Today I've got too many disappointing and I think I can laugh them in face now.

Comment: We can do it this way https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/wiki/

Comment: @AmritaDeb Your link relates to _GitLab_, but this question was specifically about _GitHub_.

Answer (score 32):

Actually, it looks like github added support for directories recently.

I was able to do the following:

- Move an existing markdown file to a new directory.
- Create a new markdown file in an existing directory (created in the former step).
- Create a new markdown file in a new directory.

In all cases, the existing pages were still there and new pages were added.

The one constraint that remains is that your file names must be unique. If you have more than one file with the same name, only one of them will show up in the wiki (I'm not sure which.. ).

Comment: So basically, it just for organising your pages, but doesn't give you anything more.

Answer (score 30):

The GitHub wiki (aka [Gollum](https://github.com/gollum/gollum)) does use directories but not in the way you may expect.

The documentation on the [Gollum wiki](https://github.com/gollum/gollum/wiki) could use some work but this is what I have figured out mostly via testing.

- All files appear in the root of the wiki no matter where they are placed in the repo.
- `_Header`, `_Footer` and `_Sidebar` files are per-directory, but inherited if there is
  none present in a child folder.
- File links can be relative to the source file (keep your files with your content).

So, if you want directories for namespacing you are out of luck.  Consider using the `{namespace}-{page}` scheme for namespacing.

Comment: the lack of sub-pages makes Gollum and GitHub wiki by extension a crippled "wiki".

Comment: Funnily enough, Gollum's github says (at least nowadays) "Pages may be organized into directories any way you choose."

Answer (score 16):

It's not the an ideal solution but the workaround would be to create a custom sidebar where you create a table of contents with links to your pages.  I find this to be better than folders anyway because it allows you to have a link to a single page under multiple hierarchies.

Comment: That is the approach I have taken, but it leaves a "Pages" part that is a huge mess of pages (over 60 in my project).

Comment: The Pages part is collapsed so it doesn't clutter the sidebar thankfully

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is still a limitation. Yes, you can add 1 level (so, 1 subfolder). But that's it! I refactored my whole documentation layout, creating multiple levels of subfolders for organisation, but that was a no-go.

*sigh*

I must say: I'm appalled by this Gollum thing. I'm surprised Github even picked it up.

Comment: I don't think this is correct.  I was looking at one of the git recommended wiki sites, https://github.com/showcases/projects-with-great-wikis .  I did a git clone and sure enough they have at least three levels of subdirectories.  Take a look at the technical-documentation/1-trackers/ruby-tracker for example.

Comment: ok, i tested it myself and it does seem that gollum has a problem with subdirectories that have the same name as even the link text.  This is kind of wierd.  I would understand if there was a collision in the actual page name, but when using mediaWiki syntax [[Link Text|WikiPage]] it does indeed seem to get confused between Link Text and actual directory name.

Comment: This incredibly ugly and redundant format seems to works [PageName](PageName)

Comment: gollum-lib does allow pagenames to have slashes, which behaves like you'd expect. Unfortunately, neither GitHub nor the "official" Sinatra-based Gollum frontend support these sensibly.

Comment: That github showcase in Ed Ost's comment no longer exists. An alternative fwiw https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-examples-of-very-well-made-GitHub-wiki-pages-for-open-source-projects

Answer (score 1):

Still no intention of adding this 9/2022.

https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/23914

Comment: March 2023: [Official GitHub Support answer](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/23914#discussioncomment-5447162): "no support, not on their roadmap".

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's a disappointing missing feature!
What I try to do is to actually have directories under a `docs` directory and in each one, a README.md file.
Not great...but works for documentation and organizes stuff.
If you want to go further, you can have a different branch only with these files.