# Can I use a Markdown file in a GitHub page?

Tags: github, markdown, wiki, github-pages

Since [the GitHub wiki does not support directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088285/github-wiki-directories), I want to put my md files into GitHub pages. However when I open them I found they are not interpreted at all. GitHub just gives me the raw file. See http://greenlaw110.github.com/Rythm/en/index.md. Any idea?

Comment: Although somewhat ghetto, you could create a simple blank HTML page that takes the current URL, disects it, and pulls the right markdown file using ajax, and then process the markdown client-side.

Answer (score 21):

The documentation isn't particularly clear on this, but given that the Markdown rendering is done by [Jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/blob/master/README.textile), I believe you need what they call ["YAML front matter"](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/) for it to compile the page.  So try putting this at the top of your file:

```
---
title: Document Center
---
```

That should be enough to trigger Jekyll.  (And then you can [get fancy](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages) and start using layouts, etc.)

Comment: can confirm this works. You dont even strictly need a title, you can just add two lines of triple dashes and it will work

Answer (score 1):

Another reason (found by experience) why you might get a raw `index.md` file, is if you happen to also have a similarly-named `index.html` file. This blocks GH Pages.

Deleting `index.html` produces (on the site) a new `index.html` with parsed markdown. The original `index.md` is then no longer accessible.