# Rendering Markdown on Github

Tags: github, markdown, github-pages

This markdown document renders fine on Github but doesn't render on Github pages. I'm unable to understand why.

Github: https://github.com/thecomeonman/MCI-2016-17-To-2017-18/blob/master/010_Formations/010_Formations.md

Github pages: https://thecomeonman.github.io/MCI-2016-17-To-2017-18/010_Formations/010_Formations.md

https://blog.github.com/2016-12-09-publishing-with-github-pages-now-as-easy-as-1-2-3/ seems to indicate that this should work without having to do anything else.

Thanks for your help!

This seems out of date: [Can I use a Markdown file in a GitHub page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15124547/can-i-use-a-markdown-file-in-a-github-page)

Comment: Delete the `.md` extension from your GitHub Pages link (or change it to `.html`) and see what happens.

Comment: Just changing the URL didn't work. I renamed the file from .md to .html and that worked. Removing the extension altogether didn't work.

Comment: Just realised that renaming from .md to .html made the text and the table work but the images don't show up.

Comment: Might be related to this - https://help.github.com/articles/files-that-start-with-an-underscore-are-missing/

Checking.

Answer (score 1):

You can add [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) and it will work. We have multiple themes are available for your github page [here](https://jekyllthemes.io/)

Comment: As per the Github blog, if I understand correctly, it should work without needing Jekyll.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was the problem. 
https://help.github.com/articles/files-that-start-with-an-underscore-are-missing/